# No data of logged users in Tracker by Antonio Ribeiro

Tags: laravel-5.6

Hello I am using Tracker by Antonio Ribeiro.I have search for answer but the ones that I found is not solving my problem. In the file Tracker.php, I have change `'user_model' => 'App\User'` to my User model but still no data is shown in the stats panel. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I was working with local server. So I fixed it by removing the localhost IP in this block `'do_not_track_ips' => [
],`